# How to get a random element using Java Stream API?

Tags: java, list, java-stream

I'm trying to use this method to get a random element from a stream. Why does it always print "9"?

I know I can use `list.get(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))` but I only want to use the Stream API, even though it may not be efficient. How can I do that?

```java
Integer[] array = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(array);

Integer anyElement = list.stream()
        .parallel()
        .findAny()
        .get();
System.out.println(anyElement);
```

Comment: Adding "Collections.shuffle(list);" before the stream call will ensure a shuffle happens.
And one more option is to add the Random find as an intermediate operation.
  Integer anyElement = list
          .parallelStream()
          .skip(new Random().nextInt(list.size()))
          .findAny()
          .get();

Comment: I use your method ,It was pretty much what I wanted. thank you!!!